# mysql alter table will lock table?

Tags: mysql, locking, alter

When I alter MySQL table, add new column for my log table. specific statement like below:

```
alter table log_xxx add column `new_column` smallint NOT NULL after post_date;
```

Will above statement will lock table `log_xxx` if I execute SQL to insert some records when I execute this alter statement?

I make some test, execute insert statement do not include new column successfully while the alter statement still under processing. So I have no idea about the alter table add column will lock table or not?

Is there anyone who knows about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the storage engine, if you use InnoDB, it may alter table in place and not block the DML operation, and if then MyISAM is used, the update and write operations that start after `alter` begins, will be blocked until the new table is ready.

Those links maybe help:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html